# Prevent Fancybox text from wrapping

Tags: text, resize, fancybox, width

I'm using Fancybox 2.1.3 to display some text when the page loads. The problem is that it's wrapping it onto two lines when I want it to all be on one line. I've tried the width, autoSize, and fitToView properties, and none of them are doing anything.

I'd prefer not to modify the fancybox css files, since I'm also using fancybox to display some images, and those are working properly.

Javascript

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        // Activate fancyBox
        $('.text').fancybox({
           padding   : 0,
           closeBtn  : false,
           topRatio  : 0.75,
           helpers : { 
              overlay: {
                 css: {'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)'}
              } // overlay 
           } // helpers
        });
        // Launch fancyBox on first element
        $('.text').eq(0).trigger('click');
        // Close automatically
        setTimeout('parent.$.fancybox.close();', 10000);
     });
```

HTML

```
<a href='#textid' class='text'></a>
<div style='display: none'>
    <div id='textid'>The display text goes here.</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#textid
   {
   font-size: 40px;
   color: red;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#textid {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```